# Python: Data-structure and processing of GPS points and properties

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, average

I'm trying to read data from a csv and then process it on different way. (For starter just the average)

**Data**
(OneDrive) https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArLDiUd-U5dtg0teQoKGguBA1qt9?e=6wlpko

The data looks like this:
*ID; Property1; Property2; Property3...

1; ....

1; ...

1; ...

2; ...

2; ...

3; ...

...*
Every line is a GPS point. All points with same ID together (for example 1) produce one Route. The routes are not of the same length and some IDs are skipped. So it isn't a seamless increase of numbers.

I may need to add, that the points are ALWAYS the same set of meters apart from each other. And I don't need the XY information currently.

**Wanted Result**
In the end I want something like this: 
[ID, AVG_Property1, AVG_Property2...]    [1, 1.00595, 2.9595, ...]    [2,1.50606, 1.5959, ...]

**What I got so far**

```
import os
import numpy
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('C:\\data' ,'data.csv'), sep=';')
# [id, len, prop1, prop2, ...]
routes = numpy.zeros((data.size, 10)) # 10 properties

sums = numpy.zeros(8)
nr_of_entries = 0;
current_id = 1;

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if(int(row['id']) != current_id): #after the last point of the route
        routes[current_id-1][0] = current_id;
        routes[current_id-1][1] = nr_of_entries; #how many points are in this route?
        routes[current_id-1][2] = sums[0] / nr_of_entries;
        routes[current_id-1][3] = sums[1] / nr_of_entries;
        routes[current_id-1][4] = sums[2] / nr_of_entries;
        routes[current_id-1][5] = sums[3] / nr_of_entries;
        routes[current_id-1][6] = sums[4] / nr_of_entries;
        routes[current_id-1][7] = sums[5] / nr_of_entries;
        routes[current_id-1][8] = sums[6] / nr_of_entries;
        routes[current_id-1][9] = sums[7] / nr_of_entries;

        current_id = int(row['id']);
        sums = numpy.zeros(8)
        nr_of_entries = 0;

    sums[0] += row[3];
    sums[1] += row[4];
    sums[2] += row[5];
    sums[3] += row[6];
    sums[4] += row[7];
    sums[5] += row[8];
    sums[6] += row[9];
    sums[7] += row[10];
    nr_of_entries = nr_of_entries + 1;

routes
```

**My problem**
1.) The way I did it, I have to copy paste the same code for every other processing approach, since as stated I need to do multiple different way. Average is just an example.

2.) The reading of the data is clumsy and fails when IDs are missing

3.) I'm a C# Developer, so my approach would be to create a Class 'Route' which has all the points and then provide methods for 'calculate average for prop 1'. Or something. This way I could also tweak the data if needed. (extreme values for example). But I have no idea how this would be done in Phyton and if this is a reasonable approach in this language.

4.) Is there a more elegant way to iterate through the original csv and getting like Route ID 1, then Route ID 2 and so on? Maybe something like LINQ Queries in C#?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: could you add a datafile for example please?

Comment: sure. I can't deliver the original due to privacy issue. But I'll create a dummy file in the same style. Just a second

Answer (score 1):

He is a solution and some ideas you can use. The example features multiple options for the same issue so you have to choose which fits the purpose best. Also it is Python 3.7, you didn't specify a version so i hope this works.

```
class Route(object):
    """description of class"""
    def __init__(self, id, rawdata): # on startup
        self.id = id
        self.rawdata = rawdata
        self.avg_Prop1 = self.calculate_average('Prop1')
        self.sum_Prop4 = None 

    def calculate_average(self, Prop_Name): #selfreference for first argument in class method
        return self.rawdata[Prop_Name].mean()

    def give_Prop_data(self, Prop_Name): #return the Propdata as list
        return self.rawdata[Prop_Name].tolist()

    def any_function(self, my_function, Prop_Name): #not sure what dataframes support so turning it into a list first
        return my_function(self.rawdata[Prop_Name].tolist())

#end of class definiton


data = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv', sep=';')
# [id, len, prop1, prop2, ...]


route_list = [] #List of all the objects created from the route class
for i in data.id.unique():
    print('Current id:', i,' with ',len(data[data['id']==i]),'entries')
    route_list.append(Route(i,data[data['id']==i]))


#created the Prop1 average in initialization of route so just accessing attribute
print(route_list[1].avg_Prop1)

for current_route in route_list:
    print('Route ',current_route.id , ' Properties :')
    for i in current_route.rawdata.columns[1:]: #for all except the first (id)
        print(i, ' has average ', current_route.calculate_average(i)) #i is the string of the column not just an id

#or pass any function that you want
route_list[1].sum_Prop4 = (route_list[1].any_function(sum,'Prop4'))
print(route_list[1].sum_Prop4)
#which is equivalent to
print(sum(route_list[1].rawdata['Prop4']))
```

To adress your individual problems out of order:

For 2. and 4.) Looping only over the existing Ids (`data.id.unique()`) solves the problem. I have no idea what LINQ Queries are, but i assume they are similar. In general, Python has a great way of looping over objects (like `for current_route in route_list`), which is worth looking into if you want to use it a little more.

For 1. and 3.) Again looping solves the issue. I created a class in the example, mostly to show the syntax for classes. The benefits and drawbacks for using classes should be the same in Python as in C#.

As it is right now the class probably isn't great, but this depends on how you want to use it. If the class should just be a practical way of storing and accessing data it shouldn't have the methods, because you don't need an individual `average` method for each route. Then you can just access it's data and use it in a function like in `sum(route_list[1].rawdata['Prop4'])`. If however, depending on the data (amount of rows for example) different calculations are necessary, it might come in handy to use the method `calculate_average` and differentiate in there.

An other example would be the use of the attributes. If you need the average for Prop1 every time, creating it at the initialization sees a good idea, otherwise i wouldn't bother always calculating it.

I hope this helps!